# Low Quality Posts review audits show score before any action is taken

Tags: bug, review, review-audits, low-quality-posts

Usually, when you review a review audit, the score is shown as 0.

However, in the low quality posts queue, I've been getting audits that show what the score is *before* I've taken any action on it.

Here's an example:

> [image]

[This is a link to the review.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4566608) As you can see, it's an audit.

I don't believe that it should be showing me that it's a 12 score post, as this way I can *easily* tell that it's an audit.

Also, this is still reproducible today: I got [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4900657) a few minutes ago, and it showed me the score before I took any action. I forgot to take a screenshot though.

Answer (score 5):

**IMHO, the score should be random within a reasonable range for the audits.**

On the contrary of your question, it could catch people doing that audit for a bad post as they can easily click on "Looks Good" without actually reading how bad it is.

Hidden scores are bad because that is a very good indication for robo-reviewers that it is an audit.

Zero score is better, but it is not complete. Zero score might trigger robo-reviewers to pay a bit more attention because that can be an audit.

If it is random though, then they cannot assume anything based on the scores.